# Converting Powershell command result to one line

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am new to powershell and stuck with formatting the results.
I have result of my command like below in horizontal format in a row which is of type "object"

```
Name
----
Test Mrs. User12  
Test Mrs. User13  
Test Mr. User15  
Test Mr. User20
```

How can I get only values printed in

```
"Test Mrs. User12;Test Mrs. User13;Test Mr. User15;Test Mr. User20"
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you provide some code, so we can take a look and to try to help you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

```
My-Command | Select-Object "Name"
```

Outputs

```
Name
----
Test Mrs. User12  
Test Mrs. User13  
Test Mr. User15  
Test Mr. User20
```

You should be able to concatenate them with the `-join` operator, like so:

```
(My-Command | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Name") -join ";"
```

The `-ExpandProperty` parameter takes the value of the `Name` property from each object, and throws everything else away, so you end up with an array of strings.

When you apply the `-join` operator with the argument `";"`, all the strings will be concatenated with a ";" in between each string.

Comment: Thanks Mathias R Jessen .